# Проверка на степень двойки

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода, битовые-операции, арифметика

Дано натуральное число N. Вывести слово "YES", если N является числом, которое получается при возведении 2 в какую-либо степень, и слово `NO` в противном случае.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int N, i=0, J=0;
    cin>>N;
    while(pow(2.0,i)!=N)
    {
        J=pow(2.0,i);
        i++;
    }
    if(J==N)
    {
        cout<<"YES";
    }
    else if(J!=N)
    {
        cout<<"NO";
    }       

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`std::has_single_bit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/has_single_bit)

Comment: ``if(J!=N) `` лишнее. Потому что если два числа могут быть или равны или не равны. И если условие на равенство не выполняется, то они не равны. Незачем ещё раз проверять.

Comment: `std::pow()` работает с числами с плавающей точкой и может выдавать неточные ответы. Если вам нужна целочисленная степень двойки, то лучше `1 << i`. (Но здесь лучше `std::has_single_bit`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конечно, ваш код можно попытаться исправить как

```
int main()
{
    int N, i=0, J=0;
    cin>>N;
    while(pow(2.0,i)<=N)
    {
        J=pow(2.0,i);
        i++;
    }
    if(J==N)
    {
        cout<<"YES";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"NO";
    }
}
```

Но смысла в этом нет. Поскольку, если точно *натуральное*, т.е. нулем быть не может, то достаточно этого:

```
unsigned int N;
cin >> N;
cout << (N&(N-1) ? "NO" : "YES");
```

И вообще, не надо привлекать вычисления с плавающей точкой туда, где нужна целочисленная арифметика.

Намек: степень двойки в бинарной записи имеет вид `0..010..0`, словом, с единственной единичкой внутри...

Comment: Спасибо друг